# Using JavaScript to dynamically change display style in img tags

Tags: javascript, onerror

I show links to 240 images on a page. The real images are uploaded by users.  I tried to avoid showing an empty image if users did not upload it yet. jQuery did not work for me because of conflicts, so I have to do it in pure JavaScript.

image(s) links:

```
<img class="photo240" src="http://www.example.com/i/%%GLOBAL__AuthorID%%/p/b01.jpg" onerror="imgError()">
```

My JavaScript:

```
function imgError()
{
    alert('The image could not be loaded.');
    var _aryElm=document.getElementsByTagName('img');  //return an array with every <img> of the page
    for( x in _aryElm) {
        _elm=_aryElm[x];
        _elm.className="photo240off";
    }
}
```

The style `photo240off` equals to `display:none`.

Right now, whenever an image misses, all the images are turned to style photo240off and I want only the missing image to be hidden. So there is something wrong with my script.

(the overall script works well, because I get the alert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` to get the image with the error.

Change to:

```
onerror="imgError(this)"
```

Then the function can be:

```
function imgError(el) {
    alert('The image could not be loaded.');
    el.className = "photo240off";
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, just got an unaccepted answer to an almost-identical answer to mine that was added like 2 minutes after mine and upvoted... ah, the SO injustice...

Comment: We both answered at about the same time. He can only accept one.

Comment: Sorry Barmar, in my page, your answer showed 2nd, and I accepted both with the imposed delay! Thanks again.

Comment: You can't accept both. When you accepted mine, you un-accepted Shomz's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the image from your onerror call and change the class only for that one.

Something like this:

HTML

```
<img class="photo240" src="example.jpg" onerror="imgError(this)">
```

JS

```
function imgError(el) {
    el.className="photo240off";
}
```

Comment: @mifi79, thank you, I've added a CSS rule to hide the missing ones: http://jsfiddle.net/66ctv/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! There are so many complicated solution in jquery, this is the simplest one! Grateful!

Comment: Yeah, your code was iterating over every single image, yet you only needed specific ones. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best. You're welcome. :)